# getting error 1004 method range of object global failed while creating a macro for deleting all rows above a row containg a specific word

Tags: excel, vba

Getting error

> 1004 method range of object global failed

While creating a macro for deleting all rows above a row containg a specific word groupid and trying to save it as xls and group id is prsent in Column A only

```
Sub ron()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rownumber As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim sf As String
    Dim filename As String

    sf = Application.GetOpenFilename(sf)

    Set wk = Workbooks.Open(sf)

    wk.Activate

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If (Range("A" & i).Value = "groupid") Then
            Range("A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Delete '**-getting error here
        End If
    Next i

    filename = wk
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=("E:\WorkbookName1.xls")

End Sub
```

Comment: When `i = 1` you would be trying to delete row 0.

Comment: Thanks Rory .got it